# When is the class "active" assigned in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to decide between using $(document).ready(function(){}) and window.onload. Assuming that I need to assign focus based on receiving the "active" class on a span, when does the class actually load in terms of on document ready, or with the various images, scripts, etc...

Comment: If the class is initially exposed by the element, you can access it as soon as the document is ready. If it is added dynamically by a script, you will have to wait for that script to run, and neither `ready()` nor `on("load")` can help you with that.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thank you for that information, I think I see where the issue is coming from, as it seems my script is attempting to load with nothing to attach to.